# Passing extra context to Django Haystack template

Tags: django, get, django-forms, django-haystack

Setting up a search page with Django Haystack involves putting in their URLconf snippet `url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'))`. However, this means (at least from my extremely basic understanding of Django/MVC), that there is no simple way to pass extra context (i.e. an extra dictionary key/value) to be rendered onto the page.

In particular, I want to customize a search field to mirror the variable passed onto the page from a GET request:

```
<form method="get" action=".">
<input type="text" name="q" value="">
<!-- result html here -->
</form>
```

Say the parameter `?q=twitter` is attached to the URL as part of a GET request; I'd like to make the `value` selector equal to `twitter`. If I had control of the view, I would likely do it something like this:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    q = request.GET['q']
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'q': q})
```

And then use `q` as the value for the `value` selector in the HTML `<input>`.

Is there any way to accomplish this in a simple manner, besides editing the Haystack source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accomplished this using a custom context processor:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_search_query(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    print search_query
    return {
        'search_query':search_query
    }
```

Then, simply call `{{ search_query }}` in any of your HTML templates.

Answer (score 9):

You can **sub-class** the Haystack View to add to the context:

Create a `views.py` file in your search app (if you don't have one). And then make sure you import the Haystack view. Then you can create a sub-class like so:

```
import haystack.views

class SearchView(haystack.views.SearchView):
    """
    We subclass the base haystack view in order to add context.
    """

    def extra_context(self):
        return {
            'yourValue': yourValue,
        }
```

Don't forget to change the path to the view in your `urls.py`, from within your Search app:

```
from yourSite.apps.search.views import SearchView
```

Answer (score 2):

Haystack already pass you the query. The template variable is called query:

```
<div>Your query was {{ query }}</div>
```

If you still need more things in the context, then you have to use the basic_search method. You have to create your view and call the basic_search. So, in views.py:

```
from haystack.views import basic_search

def yourview(request):
    ...
    return basic_search(request, extra_context={ 'foo': 'boo', })
```

There are more parameters you can set in case you want:

```
basic_search(request, template='search/search.html', load_all=True, form_class=ModelSearchForm, searchqueryset=None, context_class=RequestContext, extra_context=None, results_per_page=None)
```

Curiously, all of those can be called directly using the SearchView() from urls except for extra_context. In urls.py:

```
from haystack.views import SearchView
...
url(r'^$', SearchViewtemplate='path/to/your/template', load_all=True, form_class='YouForm', searchqueryset=AQuerySet, context_class=RequestContext, results_per_page=10), name='the_name_you_want')
```

None of the parameters are required. event

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new SearchView based on generic_views i.e. `haystack.generic_views.SearchView` then you will need to move it to the `get_context_data` function instead of `extra_context` as mentioned here 
https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/views_and_forms.html#upgrading

Example: Below I'm adding the spelling suggestion to the context dictionary

```
from haystack.generic_views import SearchView

# Custom view.
class MySearchView(SearchView):

    template_name = 'search/search.html'
    queryset = SearchQuerySet().all()
    form_class = SearchForm  

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(MySearchView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        # Add any additional context data we need to display in forms
        spell_suggestion = self.get_form().get_suggestion()
        context['spell_suggestion'] = spell_suggestion

        return context
```

This context variable can then be accessed in `search.html` as `{{ spell_suggestion }}`

Hope it helps :)